# Splitting string and displaying on site in 2 blocks (C#)

Tags: c#, string, split, logic

I have strings for products that looks as follows:

> Super fin og enkel skjorte med regular fit og klassisk button down
>   krave. Den lukkes med knapper foran og har to brystlommer.
>
> Farve: Navy
>
> Materiale: 100% bomuld

What I want to do is consistently being able to split this string up, so that I can display the first part in a description, and the other ones (Farve: ..., Materiale: ...) in a details section.

I have tried with splitting on Environment.NewLine, but it doesn't catch the lines.
There might be more paragraphs than one in the top part (the description).

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Farve` always delimiting the description?

Comment: I don't think it does. That's the problem. I was thinking about the colons, cause I don't think we use them at all in the first part.

Comment: Then it's very difficult for us to help. You must first analize all the cases to find a common separator

Comment: Yea I know you're right. I will keep looking for something. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating line-by-line and determine if the line is part of the description or if it's a "detail". The only requirement is that you know all of the possible details beforehand.

Something like this might work (not tested):

```
string[] detailTypes = {"Farve:", "Materiale:"}; // Add any number of details here if there are more

StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder();
List<String> details = new List<String>();

foreach (string line in new LineReader(() => new StringReader(text))) // text is the whole string
{
    bool isDetail = false;
    foreach(string det in detailTypes)
    {
        if(line.StartsWith(det))
        {
            isDetail = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isDetail)
        details.Add(line);
    else
        description.AppendLine(line);
}
```

After running the "text" through this code, you'd find that your description stringbuilder is the entire description, and the details are in a List of strings.

You can get the string value of the description like this: `description.ToString()`

This only works if all of your details are in the array at the top of the code, though. However, if you don't know all of the possible details, and they have no unique delimiters, the computer can't know them, either.

**Alternative:**

You could use the colons if you don't know the details. Instead of `if(line.StartsWith(det))`, you could do something like `if(line.Contains(":"))`

If you choose this approach, get rid of the inner foreach loop and the detailTypes array.

**Edit:**

Edited to include the suggestion by Jorge Turrado

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Better dont use string += string.
StringBuilder has better performance and it is easy to use

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(""); // AddText
sb.AppendLine("");  //AddLine
sb.ToString(); // Get the result string
```

Comment: Good catch! I've edited my answer to include this. It could use other improvements, too, but this is an important concept. Thanks!